# Null reference error reading application data with a background service

Tags: android

I'm saving and object

```
saveObject(myKey, object);

static public void saveObject(String key, Object value){

    try{

        FileOutputStream fos = MainActivity.getAppContext().openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(value);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        Log.e("TAG", "Stack trace is " + Log.getStackTraceString(ioe));
    }
}
```

While my application is open, I can load the object

```
Object object = loadObject("myKey")

static public Object loadObject(String key){

    try {

        FileInputStream fis = MainActivity.getAppContext().openFileInput(key);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object object = is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        return object;

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        Log.e("TAG","Stack trace is "+Log.getStackTraceString(ioe));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Stack trace is "+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }

    return null;
}
```

When my application is closed, I'm using a broadcast receiver to load the object when the receiver receives a certain intent, but I get a null reference error in my `loadObject` method

```
//Error receiving broadcast Intent....
//Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileInputStream android.content.Context.openFileInput(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
FileInputStream fis = MainActivity.getAppContext().openFileInput(key);
```

I think this may have to do with the fact that I use a background service to register my receiver, as I cannot reigster it in the manifest.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Is your MainActivity live?

Comment: What do you mean is it live?

Comment: Instantiated. Does it even exist?

Comment: Well not when my application is closed.

Comment: Maybe that's the null reference. The service is executing but your Main is null?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I thought the background service could run on its own and use classes in the application. I guess not huh?

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream fis = MainActivity.getAppContext().openFileInput(key);
```

For this line **MainActivity.getAppContext()** part seems to your problem.

What is **MainActivity**? Is it an instance of your Activity? You cannot reach activities like that, especially when the app is closed.

You need to use Application Context of your Application class.

Like this Application.instance().getApplicationContext()

Comment: Why can't I reach activities like that? Can I still access other classes, jut not activities when my application is closed?

Comment: @the_prole First, you need to study for Activity LifeCycle. Then you will understand. You cannot create an instance of an Activity like an Object. Every Activity has its own context. You have to pass its context to your service or other classes. If your activity destroyed, you cannot reach its context.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the reasoning now, just not the syntax. If I have a class Main, and I have a public field context, accessing the public field with Main.context does not instantiate Main right?

Comment: How do I get an instance of application? My application is closed when I get this error.

Comment: I am having the same problem with your suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563234/initializing-an-application-object-and-calling-a-method-on-it-while-application/35563265#35563265

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `FileInputStream fis = MainActivity.getAppContext().openFileInput(key);`

You could do this instead (we do this for a background service we have):

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
```

You have to run the MainActivity application at least once to create the service and get the application context.

Comment: Thank but why can't I do it the way I'm doing right now? When the application  closes, do I lose the instance of Main? I thought it was like accessing a static method. Isn't main just a class?

Comment: I am having the same problem with your suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563234/initializing-an-application-object-and-calling-a-method-on-it-while-application/35563265#35563265