# Initializing an Application object and calling a method on it while application is closed results in null reference error

Tags: android

I'm saving an object

```
saveObject(myKey, object);

static public void saveObject(String key, Object value){

    try{

        Application application = new Application();
        FileOutputStream fos = application.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(value);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        Log.e("TAG", "Stack trace is " + Log.getStackTraceString(ioe));
    }
}
```

While my application is open, I can load the object

```
Object object = loadObject("myKey")

static public Object loadObject(String key){

    try {

        Application application = new Application();
        FileInputStream fis = application.getApplicationContext().MainActivity.getAppContext().openFileInput(key);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object object = is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        return object;

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        Log.e("TAG","Stack trace is "+Log.getStackTraceString(ioe));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Stack trace is "+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }

    return null;
}
```

When my application is closed, I use a broadcast receiver to load the object, but I get a null reference error in my `loadObject` method

```
//Error receiving broadcast Intent....
//Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
FileInputStream fis = application.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("songObjectList.ser");
```

I think this may have to do with the fact that I use a background service to register my receiver, as I cannot register it in the manifest.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never be creating an application object.  There is one of these per app, and the Android system will make it.

Comment: Okay, but I can't reference the method getApplicationContext() from a static context ... also My application is closed when I call this method

Comment: Your activity may be closed, your application isn't-  or you wouldn't be executing anything.  Sounds like you have an architectural problem.  If you need to access a context outside of any Activity, you need a Service.

Comment: Yes, in fact I am using a service to access the class that contains the static methods `saveObject()` and `loadObject()` ... all while my application is closed

Comment: If you have a Service you don't need to get the application context-  the service is a context.  Just call openFileInput on the service.  And once again-  if your application was closed you wouldn't be running at all.  Your activity is closed, not your app.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. So if an application is using a service does that mean the application is never closed?

Comment: Yes.unless Android kills you to reclaim memory